# Why my this.props.data coming undefined anywhere before render function?

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-state-management

Data is passing from parent to child accordingly hence its showing inside render function but I am unable to use that to a async function which I need to run before the render.

If you see the `data.title` and `data.link` all showa under the render function but for some reason they are showing this error:

`×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'link' of null`

What can I alternatively do?

```
 export default class Highlight extends Component {

state = {
    htmlString: ''
}

 fetchActivity = () => {

    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'api/singleactivity',
        data: { activityLink: "http://play.fisher-price.com" + this.props.data.link }
    })
        .then((res) => {
            this.setState({
                htmlString: res.data
            })
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log('There was an error fetching data', err);
        })

}

componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchActivity()
}

 render() {

    if (this.props.visibility.highlight) {

        return (
            <div>
                <section className="card bg-info"
                    aria-label="Book Detail">
                    <div className="bg-secondary">
                        <h2>{this.props.data.title}</h2>
                        <h2>{this.props.data.link}</h2>
                        <h2>{this.props.data.imageLink}</h2>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div className="row" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.htmlString }}>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div className="bg-warning">
                        {!this.props.visibility.favorites ?
                            <button onClick={() => this.addToFavorites()}> Favorite</button> :
                            <button onClick={() => this.removeFromFavorites()}> Remove</button>}
                    </div>
                </section>
                <br />
            </div>
        )
    } else {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, mixing fetch calls and view code or using dangerouslySetInnerHTML apart, your prop `this.props.data` does not always hold a value and this is the direct source of your issue.

So surely you're using your component this way `<Highlight data={stuff} ... />` you can change it to something like `{stuff ? <Highlight data={stuff} ... /> : null}` so the component won't be created in the first place if the input data is not ready yet.

Comment: Thanks! this solved the error. however, although `data.link` is changing but the axios  is fetching only the first item that is being clicked. i guess that's another issue though.

Comment: @ShahriarFiroz yes, this is a case where you can abuse of « key » like so ˋ<Highlight key={data? data.link: '-'} ... />` (this is a quick fix that should work). Highlight would need to be recreated when the key changes. Or you can implement a componentWillUpdate/DidUpdate. Another way (my preferred) would be to use an external store (redux or others) and do api calls outside of React components tree (using redux-thunks or redux-saga...) and handle loading logics using redux actions or similar mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is :

```
{this.props.data ? this.props.data.title : ''}

{this.props.data ? this.props.data.link: ''}
```